# Unable to scrape text from a div tag using Cheerio js node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to learn about webscraping and how to use cheerio.js for scraping text from DOM elements. Now, here is my problem. I have a div tag inside which I have another div tag and then inside the second div tag, I have a a

tag and I want to extract the text from the

tags. How do  I go about it ?

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

    //All the web scraping magic will happen here

    url = 'https://ihub.co.ke/jobs';

    // The structure of our request call
    // The first parameter is our URL
    // The callback function takes 3 parameters, an error, response status code and the html

    request(url, function(error, response, html){

        // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request

        if(!error){
            // Next, we'll utilize the cheerio library on the returned html which will essentially give us jQuery functionality

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            console.log('Html data',$);

            // Finally, we'll define the variables we're going to capture

            var title;
            var json = { title : ""};


            thing = $(".container-fluid-post-job-link").text();


            console.log('Thing',thing);


        }
    })


})

app.listen('8081')

console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');

HTML
<div class="container-fluid jobs-board">
<div class="container-fluid post-job-link">
<p>Advertise a Job Vacancy for KES 1,500 for 2 months.</p>
<p><a href="/myjobs" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-block">Post Job</a></p>
</div>


//I want to extract text from the 2 <p> tags that are inside the <div> tag which has a class = container-fluid post-job-link
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use correct query selector, use `.container-fluid.post-job-link` instead of `.container-fluid-post-job-link`, following example may help you

```
thing = $(".container-fluid.post-job-link").text();
```

or particular text

```
thing = $(".container-fluid.post-job-link").find('a').first().text();
```